# How can I rename a node in TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I used a TreeView in my WinForms application.

In this application, I add a node to the TreeView. Now I want to rename (not to change text) a node. In other words, I want to change the name property of a new node.

Please tell me how I can do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that it's simpler than you think. Each [`TreeNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx) item exposes a [`Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.name.aspx) that allows you to get or set the name of that particular node.

**So, to change the name of the currently selected node in your `TreeView`, all you have to do is set its `Name` property to a new string value.** For example:

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode.Name = "NewNodeName";
```

As you've asked, this will not affect the text that is displayed for that particular node. If you want to change that, you can set the node's [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.text.aspx).